# Overwriting a txt file in the assets using a for condition

Tags: android, text, printing, save, overwrite

I have an txt file in the assets and in my code in a for loop there is a "                   System.out.println(elem.text());". I want to overwrite each line of this txt. How can i do it?

Comment: you cant edit a file in assets.

Comment: putting more complete code definitely helps here.  Adding a little bit of code into an english sentence doesn't help to answer question

Comment: can you expand a bit on what you're trying to accomplish so that we might be able to offer a solution